# Cannot download CiviVolunteer 4.7-2.2.2

Tags: civivolunteer

I am unable to download Civivolunteer 4.7-2.2.2 which is necessary for me because prior versions do not work with the current version of Civicrm. It does not appear in the extensions directory and it is not listed on the civivolunteer page. https://civicrm.org/extensions/civivolunteer

When will 2.2.2 become available for download through the extensions directory? Or is there a direct link to download and install manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/tree/4.7.21-2.2.2). Just unzip and place in your extensions directory.